# WebEngineView: Waiting for object from QWebChannel to start loading the page

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I have this qml file:

```
WebEngineView {
  id: webView
  objectName: "webView"
  url: current_url
  anchors.fill: parent
  WebEngineScript {
    id: myscript
    injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
    sourceUrl: "myscript.js"
    worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
  }
  WebEngineScript {
    id: qwebchannel
    injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
    sourceUrl: "qwebchannel.js"
    worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
  }
  userScripts: [ myscript, qwebchannel ]
}
```

and this javascript file 'myscript.js':

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:12345");

socket.onclose = function()
{
  console.error("web channel closed");
};
socket.onerror = function(error)
{
  console.error("web channel error: " + error);
};
socket.onopen = function()
{
  window.channel = new QWebChannel(socket, function(channel) {                                                                                                                             
    window.custom_obj = channel.objects.custom_obj;
    console.log("custom_obj loaded");                                                                                                                                                                          
  });
};
```

The page loaded in the WebEngineView is an html file where I want to access to window.custom_obj variable.
The problem is that the page is loaded too fast and the variable doesn't exist yet.

Is there any way to delay the loading of the page ?
My goal is to be sure that window.custom_obj is accessible when the page start to load.

Comment: did you try loading scripts directly and not from file?